# Deployment of java application in tomcat webserver with docker

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, deployment

I have doubt on deployment of a simple java application with tomcat webserver in docker. My doubts is:

1. do i need to make 2 docker images(one for java application other for installing tomcat) for it?

   - if yes, is it possible to run it using single docker container.
   - if no, then how to run it?

Please anyone explain the process I'm new to docker

Comment: I think It has to be a single image with installed Tomcat and a war inside. By the way, would not it be easier to use, for instance, Spring Boot? Then u have a .jar file which can easily be run in the docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need separate containers for java and tomcat.

There is already [an image for tomcat](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/).

You can define your own image on top of it by defining a `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.15

RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

ADD your-app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
```

Where the second command removes content from tocmcats `webapps` folder (there is some default webapp). And the third command adds `your-app.war` into the image instead of `ROOT.war` allowing the app to serve http requests on root path.

You can build the image with:

```
docker build -t your-app:your-app-web .
```

And run the app with

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 your-app:your-app-web
```